# How do I get a button on the top-right corner beside my bootstrap 5 card?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

How do I get a button on the top right corner beside my bootstrap card?

My code so far:

```
<div className="row p-5 m-2">
          {savedEpisodes?.map((saved) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-2" key={saved.episode.id}>
                <div style={{ color: "white" }}>X</div>
                <div className="card">
                  <div style={{ color: "white" }}>X</div>
                  <img
                    src={saved.episode.images[1].url}
                    alt="podcastimg"
                    className="card-img-top"
                  />
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      <Link to={`/episode/${saved.episode.id}`}>
                        <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "white" }}>
                          {saved.episode.name}
                        </span>
                      </Link>
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ color: "white" }}>X</div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

I was testing out different position, so far i can only get it rendered on the top and bottom.
I'm trying to get a button on the top right corner, besides my bootstrap card, example shown below:

where I marked the black X.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try right:0; or float:right

Comment: @Crystal where would I put that?

Comment: inside here <div style="color:white;float:right" >X</div>

Comment: On the second X div tag style add POSITION: RELATIVE. and on the button add position absolute and set right and top to required space.

Answer (score 0):

Set card position relative and button position absolute, try right, top

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below code

HTML

```
<div className="row p-5 m-2">
    {savedEpisodes?.map((saved) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-2" key={saved.episode.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <div class="x-icon">X</div>
            <img
              src={saved.episode.images[1].url}
              alt="podcastimg"
              className="card-img-top"
            />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <Link to={`/episode/${saved.episode.id}`}>
                  <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "white" }}>
                    {saved.episode.name}
                  </span>
                </Link>
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.x-icon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

If you want x icon more top right then you can apply a negative value.

Example

```
 .x-icon{
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      right: -10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Position a button on the top-right corner of a element is not very usual in bootstrap
if your not very used to with css (like me). But I think badge with pill has similar functionality and can be used as an alternative.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/badge/#positioned